# Replace values based on multiple conditions of two array?

Tags: python, numpy

Assume that I have two arrays

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5, 4))
>>> a
array([[1, 6, 7, 4],
       [2, 7, 4, 2],
       [9, 3, 6, 4],
       [9, 6, 8, 2],
       [7, 2, 9, 5]])
>>> b = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5, 4))
>>> b
array([[ 5.,  8.,  6.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  8.,  4.,  8.],
       [ 1.,  4.,  6.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  8.,  6.,  4.],
       [ 8.,  7.,  7.,  5.]], dtype=float32)
```

Now I have a situation where I need to compare elements of each arrays and replace with known values. For example my conditions are

```
if a == 0 then replace with 0 (or) if b == 0 then replace with 0
if a > 4 and < 11 then replace with 1 (or) if b > 1 and < 3 then replace with 1
if a > 10 and < 18 then replace with 2 (or) if b > 2 and < 5 then replace with 2
.
.
.
and finally
if a > 40 replace with 9 (or) if b > 9 then replace with 9.
```

Those replaced values can be stored in a new arrary which I need to use it for other function.

The simplest form of element wise comparison like `a[ a > 2 ] = 1` works. But I am not aware of multiple comparison (multiple times) with same method.

I am sure that there is a easy way exist in numpy which I am unable to find. Any help is appreciated.
if

Comment: You mean something like `c[(a > 1) & (b < 4)] = 0`?

Comment: That would meet only first condition. But I have to compare within range of two arrays. Something like this c[(a > 1) & (a < 4) | (b > 2) & (b < 6)] = 0

Answer (score 0):

`np.digitize` should do what you want. The first arguments are the values you want to replace and the second are the thresholds.

```
a_replace = np.digitize(a, [0, 4, 10, ..., 40], right=True)
b_replace = np.digitize(b, [0, 1, 2, ..., 9], right=True)
```

Comment: Gone through the documentation for `np.digitize`. But not understanding much. Could you please post some example.